# Inheritance in scala without using extends keyword

Tags: scala, inheritance, sealed

I am reading the example 5.2.2 from http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf
==>

Example 5.2.2

A useful idiom to prevent clients of a class from constructing new
instances of that class is to declare the class
abstract
and
sealed
:

```
   object
    m {
    abstract sealed class
    C (x: Int) {
          def nextC = new C(x + 1) {} } val= empty = new C(0) {} 
}
```

For instance, in the code above clients can create instances of class
m.C
only by call-
ing the
nextC
method of an existing
m.C
object; it is not possible for clients to create
objects of class
m.C
directly. Indeed the following two lines are both in error:

```
new m.C(0)    **** error: C is abstract, so it cannot be instantiated.

new m.C(0) {}  ****error: illegal inheritance from sealed class.
```

====

I cant understand how inheritance is declared !! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inherit from a `sealed class` only from the same file. However, you can use that type anywhere in your program.

This is instantiation attempt: `new m.C(0)`, and it's not allowed because the class is abstract. You have to provide an implementation, i.e. at least an empty constructor body: `{}`.

However, once you try to do that with `new m.C(0) {}` you are actually creating a new anonymous class which is a **subtype** of `A`, which is also not allowed from outside (another file), hence the error. That's where you see the inheritance error.

Compare these ways to instantiate a class:

```
scala> class A
defined class A

scala> new A
res0: A = A@3fbfbd15

scala> new A {}
res1: A = $anon$1@bd978db

scala> new {} with A
res2: A = A@342fe5cf

scala> res1.getClass
res3: Class[_ <: A] = class $anon$1

scala> res2.getClass
res4: Class[_ <: A] = class A

scala> res0.getClass
res5: Class[_ <: A] = class A

scala> val a: A = res1
a: A = $anon$1@bd978db
```

Notice the type of `res1` compared to other `resX` - it's anonymous, but it does extend `A` and can be used in place of `A`.

Comment: why did you used the with keyword here ? can we use it with class too ?? cause I know that it is reserved for trait ! @Aleksey

Comment: I just wanted to show various ways to instantiate the class, but for the purpose of this answer `with` is not required.